# event sourcing: how to apply event from eventstoredb to sql db synchronously and also in the same transaction?

Tags: event-sourcing, eventstoredb

how to apply event from eventstoredb to sql db synchronously and also in the same transaction?

I found this image

[event sourcing architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2zBz.png)

there is event handler, which will solve mhy question, but I don't know what it is, is it a built-in feature in eventstoredb or we have to build it?

Comment: As a rule: how to update your read model database _synchronously_ with an event store is not a problem that you want to have.  A good place for a dialog about this would be the ddd-cqrs-es discord: https://discord.gg/sEZGSHNNbH